# are 3 connections necessary for a push button?

Tags: button

I'm referring to the 5th circuit (see below screenshot) of the sparkfun manual came with the arduino uno. Instead of connecting all three of the (+) (-) and the digital pin to each push button, can I just connect the (-) through the resistor and the digital pin?

Also a side question, in terms of physics, you need two ends to be connected in order to create pressure for the flow of electrons, but the digital wire for each push button that goes out to the arduino board doesn't have its own ground wiring that suppose to create the pressure as a couple. How to cope with that in terms of electron flow?

[image]

Comment: You need two connections to the switch, but the pullup resistor requires a voltage source, which is a third connection.  You can place the pullup either at the switch, or at the ditial pin, or somewhere in between.  You may be able to use internal software-configured pullups instead.   All currents have closed paths - but they may be *sharing* a path with a current headed elsewhere, for example, when you close a switch a small current discharges the pin capacitance, sharing the ground path with a larger one flowing through the pullup resistor.

Comment: So can i just connect the (-) with the resistor?

Comment: No, you cannot, as then you would not have any signal line.

Comment: i meant i kept the signal line, along with the resistor which connects the ground node

Comment: The resistor does not connect to ground.

Comment: i meant if it does, that's what i said in my question "connect the (-) through the resistor and the digital pin"

Comment: That is neither what you should do, nor what you have shown in your diagram.

Comment: The diagram is the sparkfun circuit that I am referring to, of course it doesn't show what i'm describing. I thought anyone who played with arduino would recognize that screenshot as something from the manual that came with it, I'll edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the internal pullup e.g.

```
pinMode(inPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

Then wire your switch between pin and Gnd.

Answer (score 1):

In order for an input pin to be able to read a real value it must be connected to something - either a power source (Vcc) or to ground.  If it's not connected to either of those and left "flapping in the breeze" then it's said to be *floating* and the input value cannot be determined.

So you need a way of switching that input pin between being connected to Vcc or being connected to GND.  That is why there are three wires - the input pin and the two voltage levels that must be chosen between.

Now an input pin has a very high resistance (*impedance*) to ground. So when you connect it to Vcc a very tiny current will flow through it to ground, thus completing a circuit.  If you add another resistance between the pin and Vcc the incredibly small amount of current that flows will only cause the smallest of voltage drops across that new resistor (see Ohms Law).  So connecting the input pin to Vcc through a 10kΩ resistor (for example) will mean the voltage read at the input pin will be only fractionally below the +5V of Vcc.

Now when you introduce the pushbutton, which connects the input pin to ground when pressed, will also connect the resistor to ground. So you have the full 5V of Vcc across that resistor, and the input pin will be reading 0V.

Without the resistor in there - if you just connected the input pin to Vcc and then had the button connecting to ground - as soon as you press the button it would connect Vcc directly to ground, which is a really *really* bad thing to do. That's called a short circuit, and it's when batteries start to explode and wires melt.

So the input pin itself is basically a voltage detector that detects what the voltage at the input pin is.  It has two thresholds known as VIH and VIL - the input logic voltage for HIGH and LOW respectively.  On the Arduino those are *0.6Vcc and 0.3Vcc* - or 60% of the supply voltage for high, and 30% for low. At 5V that's 3V and 1.5V respectively.  If the voltage seen at the input pin is above 3V then it's seen as being HIGH. If it's below 1.3V then it's seen as being LOW.